# Automate Exporting of Rasters Using Renderer in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, image

It is possible to export rasters in ArcMap by right clicking the layer-> Data-> Export:

[image: Export Raster]

You can then click 'Use Renderer' check box to ensure the image you export uses the current symbology/rendering settings for that raster layer.

There does not appear to be any geoprocessing tools that match this 'Use Renderer' functionality.

I need to export over 200 images with these settings. I'd rather not do this manually. Is anyone aware of any way to automate this process?

Comment: Not through python, it could be done in ArcObjects. What sort of symbology do you have? perhaps you could Classify and ColourMap the files instead... BTW *very* good question! this might be worth putting to Esri as an improvement suggestion.

Comment: The symbology I'm interested in retaining is the histogram stretch. 

http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E0000000CwysIAC

Comment: Are all the rasters a similar range? min:max:SD? A function like Reclass by Table followed by Add Colormap would give the appearance of being rendered.. but you will need to fill in a table of 255 input ranges and 255 RGB values (Excel or similar may help)

Comment: Encourage Esri to expose the renderer to arcpy by voting for this idea at [Expose Export Raster Renderer Settings to Python/Arcpy](https://esri.secure.force.com/ideaView?id=087E0000000Cwys) (repost of JKyllo's comment above; wording didn't make it clear what is at the end of the link)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Copy Raster Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) which does give some control over the outputs.

[image]

Comment: It won't apply a renderer though - making the tool useless for what I was trying to achieve.